# Get current display Picture Box image while its image and background image are null

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, winforms-interop, getpicture

The picture box **Handle** is passed to the external library.

After specified event is triggered, then result picture is display on the picture box.

I tried to get the picture box content to save to picture but I found that

```
   pictureBox.Image = null
   pictureBox.BackgroundImage = null
```

How can I get the image displaying at picture box beside of these two?

Answer (score 1):

Your external library is using the handle to draw directly into the `PictureBox` control's window. Unfortunately, this does not in fact result in any sort of *permanent* assignment of an image. It's strictly a one-time event; not only will it not set the properties you are interested in, it's unlikely that the drawn image will even remain on the screen if the window needs to be updated for any reason (e.g. is overlapped by another window and then exposed again).

Without a lot more details about the external library, it is not possible to suggest a specific solution. Ideally, the library itself will offer some alternative mechanism for it to deliver the image you want. Then you can use that data to initialize a managed `Bitmap` object which can then be assigned to your `PictureBox` as its `Image`. I guess one hack would be to let the library draw into the window, and then use [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy straight from the screen's own graphics buffer the data you want.

Comment: The form contains the picture box is not always on top, therefore the hack you suggested is not what I needed, but anyways thanks for giving another way to get the picture inside the picture box.